# What are the API changes in apacheDS 2.0.0

Tags: java, apache, ldap, apacheds

The latest stable release of the apacheDS is [1.5.7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.server/apacheds-protocol-ldap/1.5.7) which is released in the Apr 2010. But this stable version is not supported in Java 11. When I debugged it the issue came when getting when converting the java version to float and binary.

So to support Java 11, I hope we need to update to 2.0.0. When I try to update from 1.5.7 to [2.0.0.AM25](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.server/apacheds-protocol-ldap/2.0.0.AM25), there are many API changes and I can't be able to migrate my embedded LDAP implementation to 2.0.0.AM25. Is there any API changelog available?

And I can't find any announcements about the official release. Currently, there are milestone releases only. Is there is a roadmap for 2.0.0 release?